# CoreData: -[NSManagedObjectContext setParentContext:] + 340

Tags: marketing-cloud, ios

I'm having a crash for a few months that's affecting alot our user base. We are using MarketingCloudSDK with Cocoapods configuration:

```
  - MarketingCloud-SFMCSdk (1.0.6)
  - MarketingCloudSDK (8.0.8):
    - MarketingCloud-SFMCSdk (~> 1.0.6)
```

We also tried using with SPM, but the crash still happends.

Sometimes it's a early crash.

Here is our stack trace:

```
Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
0  CoreFoundation                 0x99288 __exceptionPreprocess
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x16744 objc_exception_throw
2  CoreData                       0x1a5bdc __43-[NSManagedObjectContext setParentContext:]_block_invoke
3  MarketingCloudSDK              0x7cb9c (Ausente UUID 96b22bf07b063ccf80b06b16ee0c69ff)
4  MarketingCloudSDK              0x585b8 (Ausente UUID 96b22bf07b063ccf80b06b16ee0c69ff)
5  MarketingCloudSDK              0x95060 (Ausente UUID 96b22bf07b063ccf80b06b16ee0c69ff)
6  MarketingCloudSDK              0x92058 (Ausente UUID 96b22bf07b063ccf80b06b16ee0c69ff)
7  MarketingCloudSDK              0x9eac (Ausente UUID 96b22bf07b063ccf80b06b16ee0c69ff)
8  CoreFoundation                 0xd564 __NSARRAY_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__
9  CoreFoundation                 0x3db3c -[__NSArrayI enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:]
10 MarketingCloudSDK              0x8fe4 (Ausente UUID 96b22bf07b063ccf80b06b16ee0c69ff)
11 MarketingCloudSDK              0xa690 (Ausente UUID 96b22bf07b063ccf80b06b16ee0c69ff)
12 libdispatch.dylib              0x3a30 _dispatch_client_callout
13 libdispatch.dylib              0x12d68 _dispatch_async_and_wait_invoke
14 libdispatch.dylib              0x3a30 _dispatch_client_callout
15 libdispatch.dylib              0x11f48 _dispatch_main_queue_drain
16 libdispatch.dylib              0x11b98 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF
17 CoreFoundation                 0x51800 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__
18 CoreFoundation                 0xb704 __CFRunLoopRun
19 CoreFoundation                 0x1ebc8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
20 GraphicsServices               0x1374 GSEventRunModal
21 UIKitCore                      0x514b58 -[UIApplication _run]
22 UIKitCore                      0x296090 UIApplicationMain
23 REDACTED                       0xfae4 main + 35 (AppDelegate.swift:35)
24 ???                            0x1052b9da4 (Ausente)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the latest bundle added to the "Copy bundle resources" under "build phases"?

Always latest bundle should be added to the "Copy bundle resources".

Also, SDK attributes should be set only when SDK is operational.

If the above does not resolve the issue, request to raise a support ticket with debug logs, crash logs, scenario in which the crash happens.

Thanks,
Prakashini

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer!

It's necessary the "Copy bundle resources" under "build phases"? Because in the official documentation only specify this step for SPM and not for Cocoapods.

Regarding the SDK attributes, We're investigating if that's the case.